# Detect if a string contains a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have a question regarding checking the `string`.

The `string` is from a `ckeditor` so user can input anything.

The `variable` name is `htmlData` and it is like:

```
test here<br />
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                111</td>
            <td>
                222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                333</td>
            <td>
                444</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                555</td>
            <td>
                666</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
second test
```

I want to detect if user add a `table` structure and I have tried

```
 if(htmlData.indexOf('</table>').length > -1){
             console.log('table detected')
        }
```

but it doesn't show anything in my `console`. Can anyone gives a hint on this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String.indexOf()` returns a primitive numeric value, specifically:

> the **`index`** within the calling `String` object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at `fromIndex` or **`-1`** if the value is not found.

These primitives have no properties, i.e.: `length`.

```
if(htmlData.indexOf('</table>').length > -1){
    console.log('table detected')
}
```

So, simply remove `.length` from your code:

```
if(htmlData.indexOf('</table>') > -1){
    console.log('table detected')
}
```

Comment: You can have it even shorter `if ( ~htmlData.indexOf('</table>') ) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Use -

```
if(htmlData.indexOf('</table>') > -1){
         console.log('table detected')
}
```

or you can find for any tag using jQuery -

```
var el = $("<div>"+htmlData+"</div>");
if(el.find("table").length>0){
    console.log("it contains table");
}
```

it would work for any tag, class, id or any css selector.

```
var el = $(htmlData);
if(el.find(".some-class").length>0){
    console.log("it contains some-class");
}
```

Comment: I believe in order to make your second suggestion work you would need to wrap it in a container `var el = $('<div>'+htmlData+'</div>');`

Comment: You will get an `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression` http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/CcxWV/

Comment: Right, have to wrap it. But not getting any error in Firebug, need to look it. meanwhile fixing the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use it:

```
if(/<table>/i.test(htmlData));
```

Comment: But this doesn't reference the OP's string (htmlData)

Comment: Yeah, you'r right Lee Taylor, i don't read the question appropriately

Answer (score 1):

why the .length?

```
if(htmlData.indexOf('</table>') > -1){
         console.log('table detected')
    }
```

This should work fine. indexOf returns the index (-1) if not found, not an array so length property is not defined

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf has no property `length`. As the name "index" indicates, it gives you the *index*.
Besides: Why only check, if the user entered an end-tag? You should also check for the start tag. And then- why not using a RegEx like:

```
/<table>.*?<\/table>/.test(htmlData)
```

To test for both?.

*CAVE!* This RegEx is not checking if the user entered a valid html-Table-tag. It's just a stupid check for the occurrence of *< table >* resp. *< /table >*.

Comment: Are you using _CAVE_ as short for _CAVEAT_? I've never heard that before.

Comment: um.. my latin grammar is a bit dusty. but as far as I remember it is a vocativ like: cave canem! - watch the dog!. Caveat means something similar: "you may" or "you have to" or "one has to". Don't know how to translate my latin grammar knowledge from german to english ;)

Answer (score 1):

It would be silly to add to the collection of same answers so, how about this method using `match`, this will tell you how many tables there are in that string.

```
var string = htmlData.replace(/\s/g, ""); 
// Trim all whitespace..

var matches = string.match(/<\/table>/g); 
// Will return 1 for your code and 2 for the demo
```

Then you would check it like so

```
if( matches > 0 ) {
  // There is at least 1 table here
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6VDPd/)